# is it possible to update the table this way using PDO prepare statment

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update my MySQL table but its throwing an error:

> 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not define'

Here is my code

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE registration 
    SET fname, city, zip_code, state, tele_no, PayPal_email, mobile_no,address  
    VALUES :name, :city, :zip_code, :state, :tele_no, :PayPal_email, :mobile_no, :address 
    WHERE id = $id
";

$result = $stud->update($sql, array(":fname"=>$fn, ":city"=>$ct, ":zip_code"=>$zp, ":state"=>$st, ":tele_no"=>$off, ":PayPal_email"=>$pel, ":mobile_no"=>$mn, ":address"=>$ad));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array(":fname"=>$fn,":city"=>$ct,":zip_code"=>$zp,":state"=>$st,":tele_no"=>$off,":PayPal_email"=>$pel,":mobile_no"=>$mn,":address"=>$ad));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
VALUES :name, ...
...
$result = $stud->update($sql, array(":fname" => $fn, ...
```

Your **`VALUES`** clause specifies a bind variable named `:name`, while the bind array you pass to `execute()` (and it should be `execute()`, not `update()`) specifies a bind variable named `:fname`. This is the cause of the specific error message you quoted.

You also have some errors in your syntax, so fixing that one problem won't fix everything. The correct syntax would be

```
$sql = "UPDATE registration 
          SET fname = :name,
              city = :city,
              zip_code = :zip_code,
              state = :state,
              tele_no = :tele_no,
              PayPal_email = :PayPal_email,
              mobile_no = :mobile_no,
              address = :address
            WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':fname' => $fn, ':city' => $ct, ':zip_code' => $zp, ':state' => $st, ':tele_no' => $off, ':PayPal_email' => $pel, ':mobile_no' => $mn, ':address' => $ad, ':id' => $id));
```

Note that the argument `$id` is also passed to the **`WHERE`** clause through a bind variable.

Comment: Sorry for the code i entered here , actually 'update()' method  used there for pass the arguments . i tried your code but showing same error ..  thanks for your help..

Comment: thank you so much its working fine , there was a small problem with in the code i used ':name' instead of  ':fname' . once again thanks..

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know PDO uses following sinax:

`$conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM <your_table> WHERE a = ? AND b = ?', [$aVariable, $bVariable]);`

I mean that you should replace your `:fname`, `:city` etc to `?`, and pass variables as a simple array `[$fn, $ct, ...]`

P.S. Since PHP 5.4 you can use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

COMENT RELATED UPDATE:

As i found out You really can use named parameters, but you should bind them after query prepare:
`$stmt->bindParam(":fname", $fn, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":city", $ct, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: [Named placeholders is one of the most well known PDO's advantages](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#named)